# Splitting complex Reactive Form into sub components doesn't validate or link to parent

Tags: angular

I have a massive form that i am trying to break down into child components to make it more reusable.

However I don't know how to link it all back to the parent efficiently.
I've been doing some research and noticed people using FormGroupDirective, in conjuction with ControlValueAccessor but cannot pin down a working example to learn from.

Scenario is simple, I want to capture staff and their direct reports, and that can be 1..N levels deep.

Below is the simplified setup of the form and setup i got to so far to demonstrate what I am trying to do.

Before all of this was in a single page which is not good practice.

Department.TS

```js
    export class DepartmentComponent implements OnInit {
      departmentForm: FormGroup;
      constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.departmentForm= this.fb.group({
          name: [],
          directReports: this.fb.array([]),
        });
      }
    
      get directReports(): FormArray {
        return this.departmentForm.controls['directReports'] as FormArray;
      }
    
      addStaff() {
        this.directReports.push(this.newStaff());
      }
    
      newStaff() {
        var staffMember = this.fb.group({
          name: [],
          directReports: [],
        });
    
        return staffMember ;
      }
    }
```

Department.HTML

```html
    <ng-container [formGroup]="departmentForm">
       <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
          <input matInput formControlName="name" />
        </mat-form-field>
    
      <ng-container formArrayName="directReports">
        <app-staff *ngFor="let staff of directReports.controls" formGroupName="staff">
        </app-staff>
      </ng-container>
    
    </ng-container>
    
    <button (click)="addStaff()">Add Staff</button>
    
    <pre>
        {{ departmentForm.value | json }}
    </pre>
```

Child component

```js
    export class StaffComponent implements OnInit {
          staffForm: FormGroup;
          constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}
        
          ngOnInit(): void {
            this.staffForm= this.fb.group({
              name: [],
              directReports: this.fb.array([]),
            });
          }
        
          get directReports(): FormArray {
            return this.staffForm.controls['directReports'] as FormArray;
          }
        
          addStaff() {
            this.directReports.push(this.newStaff());
          }
        
          newStaff() {
            var staffMember = this.fb.group({
              name: [],
              directReports: [],
            });
        
            return staffMember ;
          }
        }
```

Child HTML

```html
    <ng-container [formGroup]="staffForm">
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
            <input matInput formControlName="name" />
        </mat-form-field>
    
        <ng-container formArrayName="directReports">
            <app-staff *ngFor="let staff of directReports.controls" formGroupName="staff">
            </app-staff>
        </ng-container>
            
    </ng-container>
    
    <button (click)="addStaff()">Add Staff</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easer way is pass as `@Input` the FormGroup/FormArray

If your app-staff is like

```js
    export class StaffComponent {
        staffForm:FormGroup
        @Input('staffForm') set _(value){
            this.staffForm=value as FormGroup //<--I change this line
        }
    }
```

```html
    <div [formGroup]="staffForm">
       <input formControlName="name">
       <input formControlName="directReports">
    </div>
```

You can pass the "formGroup" in parent

```html
    <ng-container *ngFor="let staff of directReports.controls;let i=index">
        <app-staff [staffForm]="directReports.at(i)">
        </app-staff>
    </ng-container>
```

See how you pass the "formGroup". In this way you define the whole formGroup "departmentForm" in **parent**. When you pass as `@Input` a complex object, you pas a "reference" so, any change in any property of the object is "reflected" in the object.

A [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cmnvst?file=src%2Fapp%2Fstaff.component.ts)

**Update** if we want that our component can be deleted we can add in StaffComponent some like

```
  <button (click)="delete()">delete</button>

  delete()
  {
    const parent=this.staffForm.parent as FormArray;
    const index=parent.controls.findIndex(x=>x==this.staffForm)
    parent.removeAt(index)
  }
```

Or use an @Output if we want the "parent" was who really remove the element.

Comment: So how does this work with nested components where in this scenario staff member will have direct reports? I've tried to replicate your model in Stackblitz and it didn't work. Would you mind providing a working link?

Comment: @Aeseir, My bad! there was a type error in the `@Input` (just corrected in code). I add a stackblitz in the answer too